# $\sum_{m \le \sqrt x} \frac{1}{m} \gg \log x$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, asymptotics

Why do we have $\sum_{m \le \sqrt x} \frac{1}{m} \gg \log x$ for $x\ge 1$?

I thought we could compare the sum with the integral and since $1/t$ is decreasing we have $\sum_{m\le \sqrt x}\frac{1}{m} \ll \int_1^\sqrt{x} \frac{1}{t}dt = \log {\sqrt{x}}$. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Where did you see it claimed that "$\sum_{m \le \sqrt x} \frac{1}{m} \gg \log x$"? How did they define $\gg$? (What you have is that $\sum_{m \le \sqrt x} \frac{1}{m} = \log \sqrt{x}  + O(1) = \frac{1}{2}\log x + O(1)$.)

Comment: @ClementC. I saw it from my analytic number theory notes. $\gg$ is defined as in $\log x = O(\sum_{m\le \sqrt(x)} 1/m)$ for large $x$.

Comment: Well, then that's true. $\sum_{m \le \sqrt x} \frac{1}{m} = \Theta(\log x)$; as $x$ grows, [you have that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#Growth_rate) $\frac{\sum_{m \le \sqrt x} \frac{1}{m}}{\log x} \to \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @ClementC. Could you show me why $\frac{\sum_{m \le \sqrt x} \frac{1}{m}}{\log x} \to 1/2$?

Comment: @ClementC. Oh I got it from the growth rate you sent me. We just divide both sides by $\log x$ and $1/2$ is left.

Comment: Exactly! ${}{}{}$

Comment: This is a weird usage of $\gg$